# SQL mass insert based off of data pulled from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't really know if I worded it correctly, but I'll try to explain what I want.

```
Table 1 - X
id | name | blah

Table 2 - Y
id | Xid | configKey | ConfigVal
```

What I want to do is, create a row in table 2 for everything in table 1, where the corresponding id from Table 1 goes into the column Xid in table 2. I'm from a java background and not too keen on sql, so not too sure how to do this. There are a lot of rows in table 1, which is why I would like to script it out.

I pretty much want to do something like this:

```
Table1 (the object table)
1 test1 a
2 test3 b
3 testn n
```

Run the query to get populate this

```
Table 2 (the config table)
...exisitng rows
59 1 doSomething true
60 2 doSomething true
61 3 doSomething true
```

So, I pretty much want to add in a config row (all the same values) except for the id it corresponds to (column 2 in table 2 should be col 1 from table 1)

Thanks

Comment: what goes in value?And what DBMS?

Comment: I updated it with more info, the DBMS is mySql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use fixed values 'doSomething' and 'true' for all inserted records:

```
insert into table2 (Xid, configKey, ConfigVal)
select id, 'doSomething', 'true'
from table1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Select Into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdd4h271%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that link was SQL Server syntax, the syntax will vary from server to server, but the format is usually pretty close.

**SQL Server**

```
 select id as Xid, value as name, 'other value' as blah  INTO TABLE1 from TABLE2
```

**My SQL**

```
 INSERT INTO table1 (id, name,other_value)
SELECT xid, value, 'another value' as other_value from TABLE2
```

Here is a [SQL Tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-SELECT-INTO.asp) walking you through the process.

Comment: I'm using mysql, this is what I have:

Comment: I tried the second one, but the thing is I want to add in other values to (that are all the same throughout the inserted rows) that are not supposed to be copied from the other table. I elaborated what I meant in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
Insert into table2(xid, value)
select id, name from table1.
```

But you must have the Id column in table2 as an identity or must give it a default value.
(This is only for sql server, though.)